# Save and Load contents TStringGrid

Tags: android, sorting, delphi, save, tstringgrid

I have a simple form containing  `TstringGrid` with 2 columns, a `TStringColumn` and `TCheckColumn` added.  I have seen many examples of saving the contents to file if the cells contain text or numbers.  I have not seen any examples of saving with a `TCheckColumn`.  I am assuming that I must check each `CheckColumn` cell, determine its state and assign a value that can be saved to file.  Or maybe there is a more elegant way to do this.

As for sorting - again many examples using strings or numbers but none with `TCheckColumn`.  I have `HeaderClick` enabled.  On the `TStringColumn` I would like to sort Alphabetically - On the `TCheckColumn` - I would like checked items at the top of the column.

I am using Delphi 10.2.1 and will compile for Android.

Comment: Please, *one* question per post.

Comment: Thanks Tom - Should I re-submit as separate Q's or wait for responses - I was not aware of the one question per post rule :(

Comment: As nobody has yet answered this post, leave file save/load but remove sorting and post it as a new question. Please then read [**Asking**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to learn what you can ask about and how to present your question, especially [**How do I ask a good question**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and all linked docs. Pay attention to describing or showing code for what you have tried already and explain why it didn't work for you.

Comment: For editing see the "edit" button right under the tags

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough, so I repeat: **remove the question regarding sorting and post it as a new question**. Or did you not yet read the links I provided, where it is explained?

Comment: Your question is not only the title, it's ***the whole question***: title **and** body. So take note of @Tom 's advice and fix your ***whole*** question.

Answer (score 0):

Without saying you shouldn't start from here - I will just answer the specific questioN;
To keep it simple, I would:
Save: iterate through the rows and take the state of the checkboxes and prefix the string item with BoolToStr(theCheckValue)+':'+theContents of the string.
Then save the stringList.

To Load:
load into the stringList and then iterate and break the string apart using pos on the ':' and StrToBool the left portion, setting the checked item based on this.
Not got an IDE up, so haven't tested, but that would be my approach as a bit of a hack.